# Python issue - 'reverse function call'

Tags: python

I have a loop going that, instead of using while or for, is a function that keeps being called. 
(I have to do this for various reasons.)

I am at a point where it would be very useful, to, under certain conditions during the function, to skip the rest of the code and proceed to the next iteration.

I was wondering if there is a equivalent of 'continue' for functions, or sort of a 'reverse function call', ending the function..

Comment: You're going to have to show some example code. Do you mean the function is calling itself recursively? You can't do that forever, you know.

Comment: A 'reverse function call' would be `return`

Comment: `if whatever: return`

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Thanks sapi and Jonathon, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Oh, and my code would be meaningless if you weren't familiar with the bge module.

Comment: Notice that simply returning is _not_ the same as skipping an iteration, it's more akin to "breaking from a loop". To "continue in a loop" the recursion must be called again, as shown in my answer

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is called "recursion" and you can "skip an iteration" by handling the conditions under which the recursive calls are being performed.

For example, let's say that we must add all the numbers from 1 to 10, but skipping the number 5. With loops, here's how we'd write the solution, the result ends up in the `counter` variable:

```
counter = 0
for n in range(1, 11):
    if n == 5:
        continue
    counter += n
```

Using recursion, the above code is equivalent to this:

```
def adder(n):
    if n > 10: # base case of recursion
        return 0
    if n == 5: # recursive call to skip
        return adder(n+1)
    else:      # normal recursive call
        return n + adder(n+1)
```

If we call it like this, we obtain the expected result:

```
adder(1)
=> 50
```

Notice that in my example, the case `if n == 5` acts as a `continue` for the function, because it skips the current iteration and jumps to the next iteration. How? simply by *not* doing anything in the recursive call, just going to the next value. Compare this with the "normal" recursive call, where we add `n` to the result of the call.

Simply returning from the function (as suggested in the comments) is *not* the same as skipping an iteration, it's more akin to "breaking from a loop". To "continue in a loop" the recursion must be called again, as shown above.

Comment: I think the comments were assuming that the function is repeatedly called by some sort of dispatcher, rather than repeatedly calling itself. The question isn't clear about what's happening.